# FOR LOOP without a transaction

Tags: postgresql

We am doing a system redesigning and due to the change in design we need to import data from multiple similar source tables into one table. For this same, I am running a loop which have the list of tables and importing all the data. However, due to massive amount of data, I got out of memory error after execution of around 12 hours and 20 tables. Now I discovered that the loop runs in a single transaction which I don't need since the system which is filling the data is suspended for that time. Having this transaction thing, I believe, it is taking longer time also. My requirement is to run my query without any transaction.

```
DO $$DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT '
INSERT INTO dbo.tb_requests
(node_request_id, request_type, id, process_id, data, timestamp_d1, timestamp_d2, create_time, is_processed)
SELECT  lpad(A._id, 32, ''0'')::UUID, (A.data_type + 1) request_type, B.id, B.order_id, data_value, timestamp_d1, timestamp_d2, create_time, TRUE
FROM dbo.data_store_' || id || ' A  
JOIN dbo.tb_new_processes B
ON A.process_id = B.process_id
WHERE A._id != ''0'';
' as log_query FROM dbo.list_table
ORDER BY line_id

    LOOP
        EXECUTE r.log_query;
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

This is a sample code block. It is not the actual code block but I think, it will give the idea.

Error Message(Translation from Original Japanese error Message):

> ERROR: Out of memory
> DETAIL: Request for size 32 failed in memory context "ExprContext".
> SQL state: 53200

Answer (score 4):

You cannot to run any statement on server side without transaction. For some modern Postgres releases you can run `commit` statement inside `DO` statement. It is closes current transaction and starts new transactions. This can breaks very long transaction, and can solve the problem with memory leak - Postgres releasing some memory at transaction end.

Or use shell scripts instead (bash) if it is possible.